# Class does not have a mapped column named 'x' in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy (v1.2.11) in a Django environment, so I can make a few mappings between a Firebird database (used by the company's ERP) and the intranet I'm developing in Django. I'm using **declarative_base** for the mappings, because instrospection doesn't work.

One of the restrictions is Firebird itself (version 1.5), which doesn't help much, and also I can't touch the database, only execute SELECT queries.

One thing I want to do is let the users, in some specific cases, create reports and interact with the Firebird data, creating related records in my Django project.

However, in one specific mapping, I get

```
Class <class 'SalesDetail'> does not have a mapped column named 'seller_id'
```

when the query is prepared and uses a relationship. What's driving me crazy is that I'm also mapping two other relationships in this class ProductSells, that are very similar and they work fine.

First, my base mappings, that are related to the table I'm trying to query (SalesDetail):

```
class Sellers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sellers'

    seller_id = Column('seller_id', Integer)
    company_id = Column('company_id', Integer)
    name = Column('name', String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [seller_id, company_id],
    }


class Products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    product_code = Column('product_code', Integer)
    company_id = Column('company_id', Integer)
    name = Column('name', String)
    product_type = Column('product_type', String)
    product_brand = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('brands.brand'))
    brand_company = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('brands.company_id'))
    status = Column('status', String)

    brand = relationship(
        'Brands',
        primaryjoin=(
            'and_('
            'Products.product_brand == Brands.brand, '
            'Products.brand_company == Brands.company_id'
            ')'
        ),
        innerjoin=True
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [product_code, company_id],
    }


class Sales(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'

    sale_id = Column('sale_id', Integer)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('clients.company_id'))
    sale_number = Column('sale_number', Integer)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('clients.client_id'))
    sale_date = Column('sale_date', Date)
    status = Column('status', String)

    client = relationship(
        'Clients',
        primaryjoin=(
            'and_('
            'Sales.client_id == Clients.client_id, '
            'Sales.company_id == Clients.company_id'
            ')'
        ),
        innerjoin=True
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [sale_id, company_id],
    }
```

And here's the relation I want to query:

```
class SalesDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_detail'

    sale_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    sale_company = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sales.company_id'))
    sale_control = Column('sale_control', Integer)
    product_code = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.product_code'))
    product_company = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.company_id'))
    seller_id = (Integer, ForeignKey('sellers.seller_id'))
    seller_company = (Integer, ForeignKey('sellers.company_id'))
    qty = Column('qty', Integer)
    discount = Column('discount', Numeric)

    seller = relationship(
        'Sellers',
        primaryjoin=(
            'and_('
            'SalesDetail.seller_id == Sellers.seller_id, '
            'SalesDetail.seller_company == Sellers.company_id'
            ')'
        ),
        innerjoin=True
    )

    product = relationship(
        'Products',
        primaryjoin=(
            'and_('
            'SalesDetail.product_code == Products.product_code, '
            'SalesDetail.product_company == Products.company_id'
            ')'
        ),
        innerjoin=True
    )

    sale = relationship(
        'Sales',
        primaryjoin=(
            'and_('
            'SalesDetail.sale_id == Sales.sale_id, '
            'SalesDetail.sale_company == Sales.company_id'
            ')'
        ),
        innerjoin=True
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [sale_id, sale_company, sale_control],
    }
```

My query is:

```
query = self.session.query(
            SalesDetail.sale_id,
            Sales.sale_date,
            Sellers.seller_id,
            Products.product_code,
            Products.name,
            SalesDetail.qty,
        ).join(
            SalesDetail.sale,
            SalesDetail.product,
            SalesDetail.seller,
            Products.brand
        )

        query = query.filter(and_(
            Sales.sale_date >= start_date,
            Sales.sale_date <= end_date,
            Sales.status != 'CAN',
            Sales.company_id == self.company.id,
            Products.product_type == 'R',
            Brands.name.in_(brands),
            Sellers.seller_id > 1001,
            Sellers.seller_id < 9000
        )).order_by(
            Sellers.seller_id,
            Sales.sale_date,
            Sales.sale_control
        )

        res = query.all()
```

This raises an exception:

```
Class <class 'src.erp.models.SalesDetail'> does not have a mapped column named 'seller_id'
```

However, if I change my SalesDetail to this:

```
class SalesDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_detail'

    sale_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    sale_company = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sales.company_id'))
    sale_control = Column('sale_control', Integer)
    product_code = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.product_code'))
    product_company = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.company_id'))
    seller_id = Column('seller_id', Integer)
    seller_company = ('company_id', Integer)
    qty = Column('qty', Integer)
    discount = Column('discount', Numeric)
```

And if I remove the attribute **seller** from SalesDetail, and change my query:

```
query = self.session.query(
            SalesDetail.sale_id,
            Sales.sale_date,
            SalesDetail.seller_id,
            Products.product_code,
            Products.name,
            SalesDetail.qty,
        ).join(
            SalesDetail.sale,
            SalesDetail.product,
            Products.brand
        )
```

Everything works. The funny thing is: I think the relation from SalesDetail to Sales and Products are exactly the same, with a composite Foreign Key, and it works just fine. So it doesn't seems to be a problem with composite keys or my Firebird database.

When I set a breakpoint, I can see that SQLAlchemy doesn't recognize **seller_id** and **seller_company** as declared fields when they are ForeignKeys in the Mapper class (sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py).

The stack trace in the SQLAlchemy code is this:

```
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2136, in join
    from_joinpoint=from_joinpoint)
File "<string>", line 2, in _join
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 201, in generate
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2243, in _join
    right_entity = onclause.property.mapper
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 215, in property
    return self.comparator.property
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1354, in property
    mapperlib.Mapper._configure_all()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1276, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3033, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1832, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1655, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1680, in _process_dependent_arguments
    setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 281, in __call__
    x = eval(self.arg, globals(), self._dict)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/alexandre/.virtualenvs/intranet-salao/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 213, in __getattr__
    % (self.cls, key))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'src.erp.models.SalesDetail'> does not have a mapped column named 'seller_id'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a typo, but something that pops up every now and then. The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong:

```
seller_id = (Integer, ForeignKey('sellers.seller_id'))
```

creates a tuple, not a `Column`. You meant

```
seller_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sellers.seller_id'))
```

The same typo is in `seller_company`.

Comment: I can't believe this. And I thought I had double checked everything! Thank you so much!